# how to perform mithril routing with children (subcomponents)

Tags: url-routing, mithril.js

I am writing an application using mithril and react.  I need to define the routes, and so far this is what I have come up with

```
m.route(root, '/', {
    '/': LoginComponent,
    '/login': LoginComponent,
    '/Login/Email': LoginEmailComponent,
    '/Login/Password': LoginPasswordComponent,
})
```

The idea is that LoginComponent is a parent with two childroutes (email and password).  I have some common stuff in LoginComponent which are common to both email and password component, hence I want them rendered inside LoginComponent.  How do I do this through Mithril?  Or do I need to use something like the react-router to get this done?

Comment: Since there is no reply to this, I assume I will have to use a different router?

Answer (score 2):

https://mithril.js.org/route.html#wrapping-a-layout-component describes how to accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
m.route(root, '/', {
    '/': LoginComponent,
    '/login': LoginComponent,
    '/Login/Email': {
        render() {
            return m(LoginComponent, m(LoginEmailComponent));
        }
    },
    '/Login/Password': {
        render() {
            return m(LoginComponent, m(LoginPasswordComponent));
        }
    },
})
```

Mithril's router doesn't have an explicit idea of child routes like `react-router` does, but a `RouteResolver` + Layout Component can replicate some of the behavior.